# Django - Error during template rendering

Tags: django, django-templates

Please understand I'm new with Python and Django and this is my first try at learning it.

I'm trying to implement the [django-twitter-bootstrap package](https://github.com/estebistec/django-twitter-bootstrap)

But I get the following error and I've search for a solution online without success:

```
Error during template rendering

In template /home/ymorin007/workspace/sites/mmaprophet.com/src/templates/base.html, error at line 15
/usr/bin/env: lessc: No such file or directory 

LINE 15     {% compressed_css 'bootstrap' %}
```

my setting file:

```
"""Common settings and globals."""


from datetime import timedelta
from os.path import abspath, basename, dirname, join, normpath
from sys import path

from djcelery import setup_loader


########## PATH CONFIGURATION
# Absolute filesystem path to the Django project directory:
DJANGO_ROOT = dirname(dirname(abspath(__file__)))

# Absolute filesystem path to the top-level project folder:
SITE_ROOT = dirname(DJANGO_ROOT)

# Site name:
SITE_NAME = basename(DJANGO_ROOT)

# Add our project to our pythonpath, this way we don't need to type our project
# name in our dotted import paths:
path.append(DJANGO_ROOT)
########## END PATH CONFIGURATION


########## DEBUG CONFIGURATION
# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#debug
DEBUG = False

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-debug
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG
########## END DEBUG CONFIGURATION


########## MANAGER CONFIGURATION
# People who get code error notifications.
# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#admins
ADMINS = (
    ('Yannick Morin', 'ymorin007@gmail.com'),
)

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#managers
MANAGERS = ADMINS
########## END MANAGER CONFIGURATION


########## DATABASE CONFIGURATION
# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#databases
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'mmaprophet',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
########## END DATABASE CONFIGURATION


########## GENERAL CONFIGURATION
# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#time-zone
TIME_ZONE = 'America/St_Barthelemy'

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#language-code
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#site-id
SITE_ID = 1

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#use-i18n
USE_I18N = True

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#use-l10n
USE_L10N = True

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#use-tz
USE_TZ = True
########## END GENERAL CONFIGURATION


########## MEDIA CONFIGURATION
# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#media-root
MEDIA_ROOT = normpath(join(DJANGO_ROOT, 'media'))

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#media-url
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
########## END MEDIA CONFIGURATION


########## STATIC FILE CONFIGURATION
# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#static-root
STATIC_ROOT = normpath(join(DJANGO_ROOT, 'static'))

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#static-url
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    normpath(join(DJANGO_ROOT, 'assets')),
)

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#staticfiles-finders
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
########## END STATIC FILE CONFIGURATION


########## SECRET CONFIGURATION
# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#secret-key
# Generate via http://www.miniwebtool.com/django-secret-key-generator/
SECRET_KEY = '****************************************'
########## END SECRET CONFIGURATION


########## FIXTURE CONFIGURATION
# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-FIXTURE_DIRS
FIXTURE_DIRS = (
    normpath(join(DJANGO_ROOT, 'fixtures')),
)
########## END FIXTURE CONFIGURATION


########## TEMPLATE CONFIGURATION
# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-context-processors
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'django.core.context_processors.tz',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
)

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-loaders
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-dirs
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    normpath(join(SITE_ROOT, 'templates')),
)
########## END TEMPLATE CONFIGURATION


########## MIDDLEWARE CONFIGURATION
# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#middleware-classes
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    # Use GZip compression to reduce bandwidth.
    'django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware',

    # Default Django middleware.
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)
########## END MIDDLEWARE CONFIGURATION


########## URL CONFIGURATION
# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#root-urlconf
ROOT_URLCONF = '%s.urls' % SITE_NAME
########## END URL CONFIGURATION


########## APP CONFIGURATION
DJANGO_APPS = (
    # Default Django apps:
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # Useful template tags:
    'django.contrib.humanize',

    # Admin panel and documentation:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.admindocs',

    #Other apps
    'twitter_bootstrap',

    # My apps:
    'mmaprophet',
    'pipeline',
)

THIRD_PARTY_APPS = (
    # Database migration helpers:
    'south',

    # Asynchronous task queue:
    'djcelery',
)

LOCAL_APPS = (
)

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#installed-apps
INSTALLED_APPS = DJANGO_APPS + THIRD_PARTY_APPS + LOCAL_APPS
########## END APP CONFIGURATION


########## LOGGING CONFIGURATION
# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#logging
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
    'require_debug_false': {
        '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        },
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins', 'console'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
########## END LOGGING CONFIGURATION


########## CELERY CONFIGURATION
# See: http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html#celery-task-result-expires
CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES = timedelta(minutes=30)

# See: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/configuration.html#std:setting-CELERY_CHORD_PROPAGATES
CELERY_CHORD_PROPAGATES = True

# See: http://celery.github.com/celery/django/
setup_loader()
########## END CELERY CONFIGURATION


########## WSGI CONFIGURATION
# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#wsgi-application
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'wsgi.application'
########## END WSGI CONFIGURATION


########## COMPRESSION CONFIGURATION
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'pipeline.storage.PipelineStorage'

PIPELINE_COMPILERS = (
    'pipeline.compilers.less.LessCompiler',
)

PIPELINE_CSS = {
    'bootstrap': {
        'source_filenames': (
            'twitter_bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less',
        ),
        'output_filename': 'css/b.css',
        'extra_context': {
            'media': 'screen,projection',
        },
    },
}

PIPELINE_JS = {
    'bootstrap': {
        'source_filenames': (
            'twitter_bootstrap/js/transition.js',
            'twitter_bootstrap/js/modal.js',
            'twitter_bootstrap/js/dropdown.js',
            'twitter_bootstrap/js/scrollspy.js',
            'twitter_bootstrap/js/tab.js',
            'twitter_bootstrap/js/tooltip.js',
            'twitter_bootstrap/js/popover.js',
            'twitter_bootstrap/js/alert.js',
            'twitter_bootstrap/js/button.js',
            'twitter_bootstrap/js/collapse.js',
            'twitter_bootstrap/js/carousel.js',
            'twitter_bootstrap/js/affix.js',
        ),
        'output_filename': 'js/b.js',
    }
}

########## END COMPRESSION CONFIGURATION
```

my base template:

```
{% load compressed %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../assets/ico/favicon.ico">

    <title>Jumbotron Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    {% compressed_css 'bootstrap' %}

    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy this line! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <!--/.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Main jumbotron for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

        <p>This is a template for a simple marketing or informational website. It includes a large callout called a
            jumbotron and three supporting pieces of content. Use it as a starting point to create something more
            unique.</p>

        <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <!-- Example row of columns -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            {% block body_block %}
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
    </div>

    <hr>

    <footer>
        <p>&copy; Company 2014</p>
    </footer>
</div>
<!-- /container -->


<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
{% compressed_js 'bootstrap' %}
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error above constitutes that lessc (http://lesscss.org/) compiler is not available, you probably do not have it installed on your system.

There are simple install instructions on site, basically:

1. install node.js packet manager (npm, https://www.npmjs.org), for example, on MacOS from brew:

   ```
   brew install npm
   ```
2. Install lessc:

   ```
   npm install -g less
   ```